# Vite not detecting changes (vue/pug)

Tags: vue.js, pug, vite

Vite fails to detected changes in PUG files that are referenced by other PUG files. For example:

```
div 
    include ./pug/index-2.pug
```

The `index-2.pug` is placed next to `index.pug`, but Vite only detects changes for the parent file. Maybe that is because `index-2.pug` is not referenced in the `.vue` file directly. But that's a huge deal breaker! Is there any way to fix this?

Update:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: 8080
  }
})
```

and package.json

```
{
  "name": "booqall_ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check build-only",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.app.json --composite false",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "format": "prettier --write src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "pinia": "^2.1.3",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.0",
    "underscore": "^1.13.6",
    "vite-plugin-pug": "^0.3.2",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.2",
    "vue-toast-notification": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.16.18",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.3",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.39.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.11.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "typescript": "~5.0.4",
    "vite": "^4.3.9",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.6.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is specific to how pug support is implemented in your case and possibly is a low-profile problem that needs to be resolved in repo issues.

Comment: @EstusFlask: I just install pug using `npm i pug`

Comment: @EstusFlask: It can be a design flaw in whatever watching system Vite is using. I can guess it is too dump to scan through pug files and find dependencies.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After investigating this issue it turned out to be a **Design Flaw** in Vite. The framework has heavily designed based on the assumption that all markup languages work similar to Html without any advanced functionalities. For that reasons, it cannot understand any dependency between PUG files. In fact when a change is made to a pug dependency, it is detected! but the framework is too dump to understand that it is a dependency  of another pug and that other pug should be reloaded. I absolutely discourage Vite after running to this issue as we had to migrate back to Webpack.

Answer (score -1):

The Vite+Vue doesn't support development mode with reloading PUG's includes. But that's not a problem. There should be some mindset shift to see Vue components as building blocks of an application, not PUG files. So you just wrap your PUG code into Vue SFCs and use these components in other PUG code. The huge benefit of that is that you can futher extend those PUG based components with scoped/css module styles and JS code.

```
<script setup>
    import MyPug from './MyPug.vue'; // usuall SFC with pug template
</script>

<template lang="pug">
div 
    my-pug

</template>
```

The OP complained that Webpack offers pug includes smoothly. But there's a huge difference. Webpack is a bundler, Vite isn't. Vite uses Rollup.js as a bundler. So you can easily recreate your Webpack workflow:

- use `npx vite build --watch --minify=true` (you should probably want to turn off treeshaking in the rollup options).
- use `build.watch.include` Vite's options to include your PUG files for watching and rebuild on changes
- use `npx vite preview` to start a preview server
- (out of scope of Vite): use some tool to live reload when the build files are re-build. I don't mind to reload manually

Comment: downvoted because. after adding it the project fails to start!

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder that's silly. you didn't provide any error details even

Comment: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. You may need to install appropriate plugins to handle the .pug file format, or if it's an asset, add "**/*.pug" to `assetsInclude` in your configuration.

Comment: Now, it's not detecting the change like before. Nothing is updated in the UI

Comment: You don't seem to have understood the problem, one pug is included in another. Whatever this Vite is using seems to be too dumb to understand that dependency. Assume it detects the change on the included file, the parent should be updated as well.

Comment: I do 'npm run dev' which is 'npx vite' as included the package.json

Comment: This is not so simple as just detecting the change! It has to really Rollup!

Comment: i guess the problem that this change should be detected by vite plugin handling pug files. either you don't have it or it doesn't work as expected.
Test it with a test.txt file in the root

Comment: The `pug` package rocks with Webpack! Vite is supposed to support the same as stated in their documentation.

Comment: Rollup has nothing to do with Vite dev server

Comment: I really meant rollup (as the word) not the package.

Comment: Just create a Vue project and create a simple view. Put your pug files in a folder called pug. Create two files in such a way that one includes another. Reference that in your .vue file. When you start the project you will hit this error.

Comment: You recommended Vite to me by the way. That's another reason I downvoted your answer :D. You made me angry :D Vue CLI handled this somewhere already.

Comment: I know Alex, I'm just joking. I really appreciate your help :) will take back the downvote

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder pls insert into your question `vite.config.js` and `package.json`. we definitely need more details here

Comment: I included that in the plugin slice. But it keeps saying pug not hot!

Comment: Furthermore, Vite doc says it's not required

Comment: I read that somewhere, but I cannot remember where it was. I can remember they mentioned that installing `pug` alone is enough!

Comment: You could replicate the problem, couldn't you?

Comment: You can try here, even that bug is present is this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-jxhh55?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fpug.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2Ftest.pug

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder i'll check later, need some sleep

Comment: Sure, thanks. But I think Vite is not production ready yet! I've been a software engineer for over 25 years. This framework is poorly designed.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder it's the 4 version already... 3 years

Comment: Poorly designed means, they didn't see certain things when designing it. It works for people how like Html! But they didn't know anything about PUG. They assumed it's static like HTML!

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder it uses different concepts like treeshaking. needs an updated mindset

Comment: I need something that works flawlessly. If Vite has this flaw then it is a toy that should go to the dumpster :D

Comment: I ran some tests. It cannot see PUG files at all, it only sees .vue files and scans them!

Comment: I did that by writing a custom plugin and printing file ids.

Comment: Oh, this Vite is the most terrible thing I have ever seen. Another problem, it's build is not not chunked! It just concatenate all js into a big js file! I think now I really really must throw it to the dumpster :D. I don't know who developed it maybe a bunch of kids without proper software engineering outlook.

Comment: This stupid idea works, but it restarts the server and that's so annoying. God damn Vite and the person who decided to discontinue Vue-Cli.  `function pugPlugin(options?: PluginOptions, locals?: LocalsObject): Plugin {
  return {
    name: "vite-plugin-pug",
    handleHotUpdate({ file, server }) {
      if (file.endsWith(".pug")) {
        server.restart()
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: That's not a solution! I cannot change the whole project because of that. I have to switch back to webpack. And I have to make video and explain why Vite is a terrible framework so people would not waste their time migrating to that.